# Typescript: Problem parsing with forEach()

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, parsing, foreach

Seen below, `CountTargetsData` is an interface I use to parse JSON data. I want to assign the keys `id` and values `targets` to certain variables.

I have tried using a `forEach()` loop on the `Object.values()` however nothing gets printed and it breaks my code without any compile-time errors. Is there any alternative way to use `forEach()` or could another method do the job?

```
interface CountTargetsData {
  data: {
    [state: string]: {
      [date: string]: {
        [index: string]: { [id: string]: { [targets: string]: number } },
      },
    },
  };
}

const parseCounters = useCallback(
  async (responseDeploymentData: CountTargetsData) => {

    //WANT TO PARSE ID AND TARGETS HERE
          Object.values(responseDeploymentData.data).forEach(state => {
            Object.values(state).forEach(date => {
              Object.values(date).forEach(index =>{  
                Object.values(index).forEach(id => {
                  Object.values(id).forEach(targets => {
                    console.log(responseDeploymentData.data.state.date.index.id.targets);
                  })
                })
              })
            })
          })
  }
);
```

**Update Example Data**

```
{
    "stateA": {
        "2022-06-03": [
            {
                "1855": {
                    "count_targets": 1,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 0,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 0,
                    "count_targets_failed": 1
                }
            }
        ],
        "2022-06-02": [
            {
                "1849": {
                    "count_targets": 1,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 0,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 1,
                    "count_targets_failed": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "stateB": {
        "2015-06-01": [
            {
                "1832": {
                    "count_targets": 9,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 3,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 2,
                    "count_targets_failed": 5
                }
            }
        ],
        "2016-06-04": [
            {
                "1856": {
                    "count_targets": 1,
                    "count_targets_excluded": 0,
                    "count_targets_pending": 1,
                    "count_targets_in_progress": 0,
                    "count_targets_completed": 0,
                    "count_targets_failed": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try changing your `console.log(responseDeploymentData.data.state.date.index.id.targets)` to `console.log(targets)`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example json, so everyone is able to use your code snippet?

Comment: Your `console.log` would only work if the keys are correctly, otherwise you would get an execption.

Comment: @ThomasRenger i just provided example JSON data in post. see update

Comment: What's `useCallback`?  Do you have a [mre] you can paste into a standalone IDE we can use to demonstrate your issue for ourselves?  That way we can immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: I changed your typing für my environment (otherwise is not buildable) and the console.log (my output is targets) and the output is the following => only the first one (count_targets: 1
count_targets_completed: 0,
count_targets_excluded: 0,
count_targets_failed: 1,
count_targets_in_progress: 0,
count_targets_pending: 0) ... so I think I do not have a problem.

Comment: The change in typing was because of the array your example data. `[index: string]: ...` is not correct. So I removed the `index` and used the array. But as the resulting js do not know types, it should only about compile issues and not runtime issues. But give it a try.